# How to troubleshoot the problem of connecting intel edison and bluetooth headset HM1100?

Tags: debian

I have tried most solutions given in net. still i didn't able to connect my intel edison mini breakout and Bluetooth headset HM1100.

In intel edison i have flashed with ubilinux

```
Linux ubilinux 3.10.17-yocto-standard-r2 #7 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 26 09:57:06 UTC 2015 i686

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.******
```

up to pairing process is going well.pairing was successful .
connect xx:xx:xx:xx:
attempting to connect, connected:yes
failed to connect, org.error.not available.

in Intel edison bluez 5.28 has installed.

again i started working on intel edison on nextday . it not at all showing controller xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx for bluetoothctl command.
do i flashed edison.

```
root@ubilinux:~# rfkill unblock bluetooth
root@ubilinux:~# bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]#
```

what should i do

Comment: for latest and greatest stuff for Intel Edison better to look here: https://github.com/edison-fw (and wiki: https://htot.github.io/meta-intel-edison/)